# Rate the app inside the app - Android

Tags: android, google-play, rate

I know it's not possible do it the in the app instead go to the market, I want to know if it's possible to rate inside the app (with a star bar) and go to the market and translate the number of stars selected to the existing star bar of the market? Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Simply it's not possible, unless there is some dirty un-ethical way exists...... that you must not follow to remain clean in eyes of Google...

Comment: This is 4 sure an api for the app where the user collects the data and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

As far as rating is concerned, we can rate only from playstore or web. No apps can do this things. So it is not possible.

Comment: Try not to post as answer coz it actually doesn't answer the question asked, post it as comment...

Comment: @NitinMisra : ok , I will take care of this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PlayCore SDK provided by Google
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review

Also there is a Unity package
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/unity